# USB to what cable?

Tags: usb, cable

I not sure if this is the right place, not do I know how to describe this cable. All i know is that it's an USB cable and that it goes has a strange port. I was wondering if you guys know what kind of cable this is?

the strange port:
[image]

the cable:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s part of an XBox 360 controller. It’s the coupling that’s supposed to be yanked out when you trip over the cable, instead of damaging the console.

[image]
(Yes, my controller is super filthy ;_;)